# How to define a C++ function in VTK

Tags: c++, function, vtk

[image]I'm new with C++ and VTK. I'm trying to get cells ID into a `rectilinearGrid` basic example. I'm using this code, but the compiler say that is wrong with the error that I wrote in comment

```
#include <vtkActor.h>
#include <vtkCamera.h>
#include <vtkFloatArray.h>
#include <vtkNamedColors.h>
#include <vtkNew.h>
#include <vtkPolyDataMapper.h>
#include <vtkProperty.h>
#include <vtkRectilinearGrid.h>
#include <vtkRectilinearGridGeometryFilter.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindow.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindowInteractor.h>
#include <vtkRenderer.h>

#include <array>

int main()
{
  vtkNew<vtkNamedColors> colors;

  std::array<int, 16> x = {
      {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}};
  std::array<int, 16> y = {
      {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}};
  std::array<int, 16> z = {
      {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}};

  // Create a rectilinear grid by defining three arrays specifying the
  // coordinates in the x-y-z directions.
  vtkNew<vtkFloatArray> xCoords;
  for (auto&& i : x)
  {
    xCoords->InsertNextValue(i);
  }
  vtkNew<vtkFloatArray> yCoords;
  for (auto&& i : y)
  {
    yCoords->InsertNextValue(i);
  }
  vtkNew<vtkFloatArray> zCoords;
  for (auto&& i : z)
  {
    zCoords->InsertNextValue(i);
  }

  // The coordinates are assigned to the rectilinear grid. Make sure that
  // the number of values in each of the XCoordinates, YCoordinates,
  // and ZCoordinates is equal to what is defined in SetDimensions().
  //
  vtkNew<vtkRectilinearGrid> rgrid;
  rgrid->SetDimensions(int(x.size()), int(y.size()), int(z.size()));
  rgrid->SetXCoordinates(xCoords);
  rgrid->SetYCoordinates(yCoords);
  rgrid->SetZCoordinates(zCoords);

  vtkCell* GetCell(vtkRectilinearGrid * rgrid, int i, int j, int k) //I SHOULD INSERT IN HERE ";" FOR 
  {                                                                 //CLOSING THE STATEMENT. BUT IN                  
      int dims[3];                                                    //THIS WAY THE FUNCTION PARAMETER  
      rgrid->GetDimensions(dims);                                     // BEHIND WOULDN'T BE CONNECTED.

      if (i < 0 || i > dims[0] - 1 ||
          j < 0 || j > dims[1] - 1 ||
          k < 0 || k > dims[2] - 1)
      {
          return NULL; // out of bounds!
      }

      int pos[3];
      pos[0] = i;
      pos[1] = j;
      pos[2] = k;

      vtkIdType id;
      id = vtkStructuredData::ComputeCellId(dims, pos);

      return rgrid->GetCell(id);
  };




  // Extract a plane from the grid to see what we've got.
  vtkNew<vtkRectilinearGridGeometryFilter> plane;
  plane->SetInputData(rgrid);
  plane->SetExtent(0, 46, 16, 16, 0, 43);

  vtkNew<vtkPolyDataMapper> rgridMapper;
  rgridMapper->SetInputConnection(plane->GetOutputPort());

  vtkNew<vtkActor> wireActor;
  wireActor->SetMapper(rgridMapper);
  wireActor->GetProperty()->SetRepresentationToWireframe();
  wireActor->GetProperty()->SetColor(colors->GetColor3d("Black").GetData());

  // Create the usual rendering stuff.
  vtkNew<vtkRenderer> renderer;
  vtkNew<vtkRenderWindow> renWin;
  renWin->AddRenderer(renderer);
  vtkNew<vtkRenderWindowInteractor> iren;
  iren->SetRenderWindow(renWin);

  renderer->AddActor(wireActor);
  renderer->SetBackground(1, 1, 1);
  renderer->ResetCamera();
  renderer->GetActiveCamera()->Elevation(30.0);
  renderer->GetActiveCamera()->Azimuth(15.0);
  renderer->GetActiveCamera()->Zoom(1.0);
  renderer->SetBackground(colors->GetColor3d("Beige").GetData());

  renWin->SetSize(600, 600);






  // interact with data
  renWin->Render();
  iren->Start();

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

How could be fixed?

UPDATE 1: I have inserted an image of the compiling error. Should be inserted ";" for closing the statement before {}

UPDATE 2: the exact error is

> Errore (attivo)   E0065   expected ';'    RGrid   C:\vtk\VTK-8.2.0\Examples\DataManipulation\Cxx\RGrid.cxx    73

I'm using Visual Studio. I have tried to drop the last ";" but nothing change

UPDATE 3: I have uploaded all the code

Comment: It is unclear what is the compiler error? Append the question with the error message.

Comment: I have updated the question. The compiler say to me that should be ";" after the first statement

Comment: It may help if you copy the *exact* error message from your compiler into your question and mention which compiler (version) you use on which platform.

Comment: You have a ";" after your function body, which is wrong. Maybe your compiler was distracted by that.

Comment: Updated. I have tried to remove the last ";" but nothing changed

Comment: Then you should look at all the lines before the error. If the compiler expects a semicolon somewhere that means there is some line which confused the inner state of the compiler's code parser. If you cannot find it directly strip down your code by removing more and more blocks.

Comment: Can you stick the whole module in a pastebin? We can't see enough to help. It's possible the error is before what you pasted.

Comment: I have update all the code thanks

Comment: You have this line `rgrid->SetDimensions(int(x.size()), int(y.size()), int(z.size()));`.  You don't need the `int` prefix.  I first thought you were trying to cast the values, but this is unnecessary.  The std::array<>.size() function will return a value which is an int (or is easily made one).  Try just `rgrid->SetDimensions(x.size(), y.size(), z.size());`

Comment: You can't create a function inside another function. Put the code for `vtkCell* GetCell(vtkRectilinearGrid * rgrid, int i, int j, int k) { ....}` above `int main() {}`

Comment: I would post an answer but I am sure there are many duplicates for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined your `GetCell` function inside the body of the `main` function, which is not allowed in C++. Only a declaration would be allowed inside the body, hence the compiler expects a semicolon after the function header.

Move the whole `GetCell` function block outside the `main` function. If that leads to problems you cannot solve ask another question about them.